# Getting lcov to work on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, lcov

What Cygwin package(s) do I need to install to get lcov to work on Cygwin?

I tried to run lcov and received the following:
command not found

Thank you for any help.

P.S. I should point out that gcov does work.

Comment: For iconv I also receive "command not found".

Comment: Oh, sorry JustADude, I completely misread `lcov` to `iconv` (a tool I'm more familiar with). Go figure..

Comment: what is icov, if it's not iconv?

Comment: Please accept the answer by @iheanyi, the currently accepted answer is misleading as it implies the work to get a working version of `lcov` in cygwin is hard while this is absolutely not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't have a port of lcov, sadly. To get one, you'll need to rebuild it from source yourself.

If you do get it working, I'm pretty sure the rest of the Cygwin community would love to have it; there's instructions on submitting Cygwin ports on the [Package Contributor's Guide](http://cygwin.com/setup.html).

Answer (score 9):

Cygwin doesn't need a port of lcov because it can be trivially built from source.

lcov is a set of perl scripts so once you have perl installed, you can download the source and build lcov directly.

Download [tarball](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php), extract to a folder, then:

```
make install
```

Comment: Works seamlessly in my `cygwin`